# Mocking a built-in dictionary method

Tags: python, class, dictionary, methods, mocking

I need to mock a built-in dictionary method `dict.setdefault()` from a function. The function is a class method that doesn't return any values so I need to check which arguments `setdefault` method is called with instead.

I tried patching the setdefault from the function path but that doesn't work. (`mycode.Class.myfunc.dict.setdefault` OR `mycode.Class.myfunc.setdefault`) It just throws an attribute error saying that the unbound method doesn't have the attribute `dict` or `setdefault`.

Is there any way I can mock `setdefault()`? Thank you!

mycode.py

```
class Class(Class2):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(Class, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     def myfunc(self, a, b):
          self.dict_var = {}
          self.dict_var.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, [])
```

my_test.py

```
from mycode import Class

    @mock.patch("mycode.Class.myfunc.dict.setdefault") # Also tried "mycode.Class.myfunc.setdefault"
    def test_myfunc(self, mock_setdefault):
         a = {'this':'this'}
         b = ['that':,'that2']

         Class().myfunc(a, b)

         mock_setdefault.assert_called_with(a)
```

Output:

`AttributeError: <unbound method Class.myfunc> does not have the attribute u'dict'`

OR

`AttributeError: <unbound method Class.myfunc> does not have the attribute u'setdefault'`

Comment: Someone might suggest `forbiddenfruit`. Don't use it. It's poorly-implemented and leads to memory corruption, wrong results, and segfaults.

Comment: Instead of trying to check what calls happen inside `myfunc`, check that it produces the right results.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks but how would I do that if `myfunc` doesn't return anything.

Comment: By checking `dict_var`. (Also, `Class.myfunc(a, b)` is an invalid call.)

Comment: I edited it. How can I check the final version of `dict_var` without function returning the value? Sorry, I must be missing something.

Comment: You stored it on the instance. Save the instance instead of throwing it away.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Oh that's right. It works. Thank you.